# Cors Requests for POST and PUT and PATCH and so on are not working. Only GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a rails app, which has an API that people can use. Unfortunately that api apparently only allows me to do GET requests and nothing else. I tried a POST request which you do not need to be authenticated for.

My `BaseController`, which extends from `ApplicationController` is used by all the API controllers. it looks as such:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class BaseController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      before_action :default_json
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

      after_filter :cors_access

      protected

      # Give access to everyone from the api sub domain.
      def cors_access
        if request.subdomain == "api"
          headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
          headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Right now the core url for something is `api.sitename.com/api/v1/what/x/ever/y`

I can do GET Requests just fine, but when it comes to POST I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.writer.aisisplatform.com/api/v1/posts/16/comments/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So why can I do GET requests but not POST requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the backbone, you need to make an adjustment in sync, becoming look something  this:

```
(function(Backbone) {
  var methods, _sync;

  _sync = Backbone.sync;

  methods = {
    beforeSend: function() {
      return this.trigger('sync:start', this);
    },
    complete: function() {
      return this.trigger('sync:stop', this);
    }
  };

  Backbone.sync = function(method, entity, options) {
    var sync;

    if (options == null) options = {};

    _.defaults(options, {
      beforeSend: _.bind(methods.beforeSend, entity),
      complete: _.bind(methods.complete, entity)
    });

    // add crossDomain
    if (!options.crossDomain) options.crossDomain = true;

    // add xhrFields
    if (!options.xhrFields) {
      options.xhrFields = {
        withCredentials: true
      };
    }

    sync = _sync(method, entity, options);

    if (!entity._fetch && method === 'read') return entity._fetch = sync;
  };
})(Backbone);
```

By default all requests made by backbone is of the type GET, to  the POST you need to send a options object with in the fetch:

```
model = new Backbone.Model();
model.fetch({ url: 'http://api.com/uri', type: 'POST' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def cors_access
  if request.subdomain == "api"
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type'
  end
end
```

The call by ajax api would be thus:

```
$.ajax('http://api.writer.aisisplatform.com/api/v1/posts/16/comments/', {
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res)
    },
    error: function (xhr, error) {
        console.log(xhr, error)
    }
})
```

If you use reverse proxy for serving your requests, advise using cors it, I do not think that is much of the responsible rails insert headers in requests, so I'll show you an example done in the nginx:

```
location /api/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    proxy_pass http://your_balancer;
}
```

By doing so, you will not need to make anything in the rails.

Hope this help you.

Comment: you have this `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` does Backbone (i which I use) take care of this for me or can I ommit it or ....

Answer (score 0):

**rack-CORS**

I'd *highly* recommend using the [`rack-CORS gem`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) for this:

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource 'api/v1', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :patch]
    end
end
```

Working manually with CORS in your controllers is a configuration hell - you'll be much better suited to using the above code & gem to keep it clean. We have the above working in production very well

There's a [good Railscast about this here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware)